# Check user login and launch a LoginActivity

Tags: android

I am wondering what is the best way to do this:

I do queries to an API which needs the user to be logged. When the application starts doing the login, if it is correct will store user/pass in preferences.

Once we are logged, if an error of NOT_LOGGED occurrs in any activity when I am trying to call the method from the API, I will retrieve user/pass from preferences and do the login again.
If it's succesfull my program will try again the API query. If not, it will be open the LoginActivity. That's where I wonder what is best to do.

As the method to "Relogin" it's use from several activities I have decided to implemented in MyApp, a class which extends from Application and keep objects alive all the activitiy's lifecycle. But I cant close the stack of activities from there, can I? 
My idea is to close the current stack of activities and open the Login one, using this:

```
if(!mMyApp.relogin(mCtx)){
    Intent intent=new Intent(mCtx,ActivityLogin.class);    
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);                    
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

But I have to call the method finish from the proper activity but not from MyApp.
So I have to repeat all the code in every single class I use the `relogin(mCtx)` method.

Do you think I taclking the problem in the right way, or should I change the strategy? And BTW, what do you think is the best place to implement methods that will be called from different activities. I have been using singletons so far, but if the gc clean memory I might lose that information.

Thanks,
David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make `relogin` take in the Activity instance (instead of a generic Context) you can invoke the `finish` method in there. Try it out and see: it should work.

And in anycase when you use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` it will automatically destroy all Activities, so the `finish` is probably redundant.

Comment: What do you mean with generic Context? mCtx is a member of the Activity therefore an activity instance if I am not wrong.

Comment: Ah, I'd assumed the relogin signature was `relogin(Context mCtx);`, not `relogin(Activity mCtx);`. If you want to invoke `finish` it will have to be the second one because `finish` is an Activity-specific method and is not available on `Context`.

Comment: Calling the intent with the FLAG_ACTIVTY_CLEAR_TOP fromoutside the Activity it doesnt work. An error produces wich says:: Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Well, this is the question: you should be calling that using the Activity, not a generic Context. Where are you calling `relogin` from, isn't it from the Activity's main thread?

Comment: I am calling from another class, MyApp, which extends from Aplication. I am using the Activity to call relogin as 'code'mMyApp.relogin(ActivityMyFlights.this)'code' but the problem seem to be in clearing the stack of activities....

Comment: Ah. Can you change your call stack to use a Handler? That is, use a Handler in `ActivityMyFlights` and have `MyApp` send a Message to the Handler that calls `relogin`? That way the actual calling thread will be the Activity's looper thread and the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP should work? Or use `View.post` on some View of the Activity.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the checking is inside a while, which tries 3 times if can do the network query. That method is inside a AsyncTask and if 1st time fail and I close the activity the asyntask doesnt close(whereas it should as I have call the LoginActivity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) and next time enters in the while the app crash...

Comment: Ah. I've done similar things: you create a Handler object in the Activity that spawned the `AsyncTask` instance and then pass that Handler to the `AsyncTask` as part of the constructor: the `AsyncTask` can then send a Message to the Handler and everything happens in the right place.

Comment: haha I think that i bit fat fetched :D I have skip the 3 attemps and now it works fine, whereas your idea is also very good. But an AsyncTask+Handler it doesnt look good, does it? Now it works from the MyApp class but I have to add also the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: If `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` does what you want, then that's alright, but the Handler+AsyncTask is a pattern that works quite well, and one of the things the Handler lets you do is actually just use a simple Thread: the Handler handles the messages back to the main Activity that the `AsyncTask` special methods handled.